# Visual Studio nVidia nsight change cuda toolkit version

Tags: cuda, nsight

I'm using nvidia nsight for visual studio to write cuda programs.

I recently installed the new beta version of nsight with cuda toolkit 5 but my old projects are still using version 4.2 .

Where do I change the toolkit version to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest way would be to create a new CUDA 5.0 project and move your files into it.

If you want to mess with the build customizations, you can do it as follows:

1. Right-Click on your Project
2. Click "Build Customizations..."
3. Uncheck the "CUDA 4.2" customization and check the "CUDA 5.0" customization

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013 this is right click project to open menu with Build Dependencies and submenu Build Customizations